# Dynamically change input size using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using an input form to get input value from user which is an OTP . It varies based on 4 digit, 5 digit and 6 digit . so far i tried is given below, which is working but not dynamic. it requres the page to refresh again in order to show exactly what i needed

```
 if ($number_length == 4) {
            ?>
              <input type="text" id="digit-1" name="otp_number" data-next="digit-2" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-2" name="otp_number2" data-next="digit-3" data-previous="digit-1" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-3" name="otp_number3" data-next="digit-4" data-previous="digit-2" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-4" name="otp_number4" data-next="digit-5" data-previous="digit-3" />
            <?php }  elseif ($number_length == 5) { ?>
              <input type="text" id="digit-1" name="otp_number" data-next="digit-2" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-2" name="otp_number2" data-next="digit-3" data-previous="digit-1" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-3" name="otp_number3" data-next="digit-4" data-previous="digit-2" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-4" name="otp_number4" data-next="digit-5" data-previous="digit-3" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-5" name="otp_number5" data-next="digit-6" data-previous="digit-3" />
            <?php }  elseif ($number_length == 6) { ?>
              <input type="text" id="digit-1" name="otp_number" data-next="digit-2" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-2" name="otp_number2" data-next="digit-3" data-previous="digit-1" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-3" name="otp_number3" data-next="digit-4" data-previous="digit-2" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-4" name="otp_number4" data-next="digit-5" data-previous="digit-3" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-5" name="otp_number5" data-next="digit-6" data-previous="digit-3" />
              <input type="text" id="digit-6" name="otp_number6" data-next="digit-6" data-previous="digit-3" />
            <?php } ?>
```

This require the page to refresh to show the corresponding input fields as the $number_length varies.  Can we done this using ajax? and how?

Answer (score 1):

Like this? No need for Ajax (other than getting number_length now)

I also fixed your data-next which seems wrong if there are no next

Change the first line from

```
const numberLength = 5; // <?= $number_length ?>;
```

to

```
const numberLength = <?= $number_length ?>;
```

when happy

```js
const numberLength = 5; // <?= $number_length ?>;
const div = document.getElementById("container")
for (let i = 0; i < numberLength; i++) {
  let inp = document.createElement("input")
  inp.type = "text";
  inp.id = "digit-" + (i + 1);
  inp.name = "otp_number";
  if (i > 0) inp.setAttribute("data-previous", "digit-" + i)
  if (i < numberLength - 1) inp.setAttribute("data-next", "digit-" + (i + 2))

  // for debugging
  inp.placeholder = "prev:" + (inp.getAttribute("data-previous") || "n/a") + 
                    " => digit-" + (i + 1) + 
                    " => next:" + (inp.getAttribute("data-next") ||"n/a"); 

 div.appendChild(inp)
}
```

```css
input { width:350px }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```